# is it acceptable to modify migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm joined a rails project which have been going for past two months. I saw that the developers are modifying existing migrations to change column types/names? When I ran migrations nothing happens and I get random errors like, method not found. When I deubug and check the database, find that the field names are different and thats the reason errors come.

As per my understanding for each modification of database, we need to create new migration.

Is this behavior of modifying existing migrations acceptable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, once you check in a migration it should not be modified. For one project I was a part of, we reset the database on a regular basis and so people would modify migrations from time to time rather than create new ones, but it's not a practice I'm fond of.

So, if you want the default Rails migration behavior to work, no, don't change a migration that someone may have already used. However, if you are okay with working around the default behavior, it doesn't matter. Note: if you're running migrations on production to keep the database up to date, it's important that you never change a migration that has already been run on production!

Comment: In your opinion, is it ok/acceptable to modify migrations that are generated by the CLI _before_ committing them? For example, if I add a model with a reference field with `bin/rails generate model Comment author:references`, but I update `author` to have `class_name: User`, what I need to modify my migration manually? (apologies I'm new to Rails).

Comment: @LondonAppDev absolutely! It's totally normal to modify a migration to suit your needs. The problem only comes when other devs (or production!) has already run the migration

Answer (score 0):

It's all about good style. Of course you can change migrations, but this is bad style. According the guidelines you should make new migration for each changing.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is not acceptable. Here are some reasons when and why it could be acceptable or nor:

- I'm developing 2 rails applications for myself only, and I am the only developer. When I have made an error in the migration, I sometimes just fix it, rollback the migration and redo it after fixing the error. This only works because

  - I know that I am the only one.
  - I do it right after the erroneous change
  - I know how and when to first rollback and then redo it.
- In all other cases, it is not acceptable:

  - More than one developer.
  - Integrated by version control system like Subversion, Git, ...
  - Independent development done in different rooms or even location.

So I think you have the hard job to change the behavior of others. Good luck with that!